# Multiple classes for one markup in apache wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket, code-reuse, reusability

Is it possible to have multiple classes for one HTML markup? Can you provide an example?

Comment: That's basically asking for an example of how Wicket works. Yes you can have multiple classes. You can have classes for individual components, you can have multiple layers of templates each with a matching (sub)class. This is really only a very open-ended question that says "I don't really know how Wicket works. Please give an example". There are already numerous on the sites of Wicket itself.

Comment: I don't think your question is that odd but maybe elaborate a bit more if you want a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating an abstract class for a page with its own HTML file. Using the < wicket:child> tag you can add data specific to the subclass of the page with their own html file. You'd have to add the componts in the abstract class, not the subclass.